# turtle.onclick() usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So for a class I am making a program the does a function, and then waits for the user to click the turtle.  When the user clicks the screen, its supposed to "reset" the turtles position and do the original function again.  The only problem is that the program seems to ignore the onclick, and just resets itself in its own.  It look like this:

```
import turtle

jim = turtle.Turtle()

def line():
    jim.fd(20)
    jim2.lt(90)
    jim.fd(20)

def reset()
    jim.reset()
    jim2.reset()

def click():
    wn.onscreenclick(None, reset())

line()
click()
```

I've read through the documentation, and this seems it should work, but the program skips over waiting for the click and just resets without me clicking anything on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your call to `wn.onscreenclick` should look like:

```
wn.onscreenclick(None, reset)
```

because as defined now, it's calling it and passing the result of the reset to the `wn.onscreenclick` function, which is probably not what you want.